# Add lstm cell to neural network for reinforcement learning

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I'm new to learning about Neural Networks and AI. For my college project I'm trying to make an agent drive a car towards a target placed in a random position on a plane. This is my model code:

```
def CreateModel(self):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(40, kernel_size=(7, 9), strides=(1, 1), input_shape=self.input_shape, activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(70, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(90, kernel_size=(4, 5), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(768))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1024))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dense(5))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss="mean_squared_error", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
    return model

def __init__(self, load='', epsilon=0.8):
    self.input_shape = (90,120,3)

    # Training hyperparameters
    self.gamma           = 0.99
    self.epsilon         = epsilon
    self.epsilon_min     = 0.3
    self.epsilon_decay   = 0.9998
    self.learning_rate   = 0.001
    self.tau             = 0.05 
    self.memory_size     = 2000

    self.memory = deque(maxlen=self.memory_size)

    if (load != ''):
        print('|| ------------  Init model load: {0}'.format(load))
        self.model = load_model(load)
        self.target_model = load_model(load)
    else:
        print('|| ------------  No load. Initializing')
        self.model = self.CreateModel()
        self.target_model = self.CreateModel()



def Act(self, state):
    self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
    self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon_min, self.epsilon)

    print("|| ----  Epsilon: {0}".format(self.epsilon))

    if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
        return np.random.randint(low=0,high=5)

    return (self.model.predict(state)).argmax(axis=1)[0]
```

It takes a single 120 x 90 3 channel image as input and outputs a vector of Q-values for the 5 possible actions that can be taken based on the image. I read this research paper(https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00521-017-3241-z.pdf) paper and modelled my network based on it. I've been training it for quite a while but the results have been disappointing. 
I'd like to incorporate an LSTM cell to process a sequence of 10 consecutive frames instead of 1 and output the same single 5 elements array for each sequence. I tried to understand the Keras LSTM and TimeDistributed layers, but can't understand how to make the corresponding changes to my model. Please help me out or direct me to a page that addresses this topic in a newbie way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your input shape should be (1,120, 90, 3) with 1 referring to the batch_size.
With a time series with 5 pictures you want a new  batch size: (1, 10, 120, 90, 3). This is a 5D tensor.
Although I've never tried this before you could try this layer: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d
This accept the 5D tensor and output a typical 4D tensor. With this output you can simply then resume convoluting and pooling like you did before.

If you want to use more than one convlstm2d layer you have to set return_sequences=True in all but your last conv2lstm layer.